# Extracting particular element from mnesia db

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

we have a table  in ejabberd offline_msg.following is snap shot of one of the message stored in this table

```
{offline_msg,
{<<"+1">>,<<"devlab">>}, 
{1440,484625,227224},
never,
{jid,<<"+111">>,<<"devlab">>,<<"xyz">>,<<"+111">>,<<"devlab">>,<<"xyz">>},
{jid,<<"+1">>,<<"devlab">>,<<>>,<<"+1">>,<<"devlab">>,<<>>},
{xmlel,<<"message">>,
[{<<"to">>,<<"multicast.devlab">>},
{<<"type">>,<<"group">>},
{<<"id">>,<<"**99897**">>}],
[{xmlel,<<"addresses">>,
[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/address">>}],
[{xmlel,<<"address">>,
[{<<"type">>,<<"to">>},
{<<"jid">>,<<"+1@devlab">>},  
{<<"desc">>,<<"2001,104">>}],
[]},
{xmlel,<<"address">>,
[{<<"type">>,<<"to">>},
{<<"jid">>,<<"+1@devlab">>},
{<<"desc">>,<<"2001,104">>}],
[]}]},
{xmlel,<<"subject">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"1440484625:GROUP">>}]},
{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],
[{xmlcdata,
<<"mod_archive,0,https://IP/downloadfiles/avatar/104.jpg">>}]},
{xmlel,<<"request">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:receipts">>}],[]}]}}.
```

Now my question is->I want to make a search function to whom i will pass a id and this function will find if passed  ID(99897) exists in table or not.Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

match_object/2 will work (you can also use select/2 to perform the search and the extraction of some fields in a single operation) the code below does the job (example with ets for fast test but should work with mnesia):

```
-module (test3).

-compile([export_all]).

-include_lib("stdlib/include/ms_transform.hrl").

init() ->
    ets:new(test,[named_table,bag]),
    ets:insert(test,{offline_msg,{<<"+1">>,<<"devlab">>},{1440,484625,227224},never,
            {jid,<<"+111">>,<<"devlab">>,<<"xyz">>,<<"+111">>,<<"devlab">>,<<"xyz">>},
            {jid,<<"+1">>,<<"devlab">>,<<>>,<<"+1">>,<<"devlab">>,<<>>},{xmlel,<<"message">>,
            [{<<"to">>,<<"multicast.devlab">>},{<<"type">>,<<"group">>},{<<"id">>,<<"99897">>}],
            [{xmlel,<<"addresses">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/address">>}],
                [{xmlel,<<"address">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"to">>},{<<"jid">>,<<"+1@devlab">>},{<<"desc">>,<<"2001,104">>}],[]},
                {xmlel,<<"address">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"to">>},{<<"jid">>,<<"+1@devlab">>},{<<"desc">>,<<"2001,104">>}],[]}]},
                {xmlel,<<"subject">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"1440484625:GROUP">>}]},{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],
                [{xmlcdata,<<"mod_archive,0,https://IP/downloadfiles/avatar/104.jpg">>}]},
                {xmlel,<<"request">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:receipts">>}],[]}]}}),
    ets:insert(test,{offline_msg,{<<"+1">>,<<"devlab">>},{1440,484625,227224},never,
        {jid,<<"+111">>,<<"devlab">>,<<"xyz">>,<<"+111">>,<<"devlab">>,<<"xyz">>},
        {jid,<<"+1">>,<<"devlab">>,<<>>,<<"+1">>,<<"devlab">>,<<>>},{xmlel,<<"message">>,
        [{<<"to">>,<<"multicast.devlab">>},{<<"type">>,<<"group">>},{<<"id">>,<<"99898">>}],
        [{xmlel,<<"addresses">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/address">>}],
            [{xmlel,<<"address">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"to">>},{<<"jid">>,<<"+1@devlab">>},{<<"desc">>,<<"2001,104">>}],[]},
            {xmlel,<<"address">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"to">>},{<<"jid">>,<<"+1@devlab">>},{<<"desc">>,<<"2001,104">>}],[]}]},
            {xmlel,<<"subject">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"1440484625:GROUP">>}]},{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],
            [{xmlcdata,<<"mod_archive,0,https://IP/downloadfiles/avatar/104.jpg">>}]},
            {xmlel,<<"request">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:receipts">>}],[]}]}}),
    ets:insert(test,{offline_msg,{<<"+1">>,<<"devlab">>},{1440,484625,227224},never,
            {jid,<<"+111">>,<<"devlab">>,<<"xyz">>,<<"+111">>,<<"devlab">>,<<"xyz">>},
            {jid,<<"+1">>,<<"devlab">>,<<>>,<<"+1">>,<<"devlab">>,<<>>},{xmlel,<<"message">>,
            [{<<"to">>,<<"multicast.devlab">>},{<<"type">>,<<"group">>},{<<"id">>,<<"99897">>}],
            [{xmlel,<<"addresses">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"http://jabber.org/protocol/address">>}],
                [{xmlel,<<"address">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"to">>},{<<"jid">>,<<"+1@devlab">>},{<<"desc">>,<<"2001,104">>}],[]},
                {xmlel,<<"address">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"to">>},{<<"jid">>,<<"+1@devlab">>},{<<"desc">>,<<"2001,104">>}],[]}]},
                {xmlel,<<"subject">>,[],[{xmlcdata,<<"1440484625:GROUP">>}]},{xmlel,<<"body">>,[],
                [{xmlcdata,<<"mod_archive,0,https://IP/downloadfiles/avatar/105.jpg">>}]},
                {xmlel,<<"request">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:receipts">>}],[]}]}}).

test(Id) ->
    MS = {'_','_','_','_','_','_',{'_','_',['_','_',{<<"id">>,Id}],'_'}},
    ets:match_object(test,MS).
```

But as you can see it depens on the structure of your record, and particularly on the order of the key/value list `[{<<"to">>,<<"multicast.devlab">>},{<<"type">>,<<"group">>},{<<"id">>,<<"99897">>}]`. If you are absolutly confident that the order in this lis will never change, fine. If you know that the size will never change then you can use a list of match spec like:

```
test(Id) ->
    MS = [{{'_','_','_','_','_','_',{'_','_',['_','_',{<<"id">>,Id}],'_'}},[],['$_']},
          {{'_','_','_','_','_','_',{'_','_',['_',{<<"id">>,Id},'_'],'_'}},[],['$_']},
          {{'_','_','_','_','_','_',{'_','_',[{<<"id">>,Id},'_','_'],'_'}},[],['$_']}],
    ets:select(test,MS).
```

But I recommend you to store the data in ets keeping in mind the different searches you will have to do and split your data in more elementary and sensible fields: before storing the data you have all the power and speed of erlang to perform analysis, while in matchspec you have an extremely reduce set of capabilities and reltively poor speed for complex matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mnesia's [`match_object/3` function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#match_object-3) (or it's dirty equivalent) to find a matching object in a table.

Alternatively, you can use [the `qlc` module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/qlc.html) to query the Mnesia table.